# Add some spheres in these particular positions?

Tags: swift, scenekit

[image]

I have a SCNBox below, I want to add some spheres in these position, how can I do that?

Comment: You mean you need to add shapes inside the box? Or you wanna put them on the box surface?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add spheres at these points of the special SCNBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983862/add-spheres-at-these-points-of-the-special-scnbox)

Comment: on the box surface please

Answer (score 0):

```
func addShape(pos: SCNVector3, to: SCNNode) {

    let radius = Float(0.05)

    let objectSph = SCNSphere(radius: CGFloat(radius))
    let object = SCNNode(geometry: objectSph)
    let position = SCNVector3Make(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z)

    object.position = position
    object.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
    to.addChildNode(object)
}
```

In playground:

```
import SceneKit
import PlaygroundSupport

func addShape(pos: SCNVector3, to: SCNNode) {

    let radius = Float(0.05)

    let objectSph = SCNSphere(radius: CGFloat(radius))
    let object = SCNNode(geometry: objectSph)
    let position = SCNVector3Make(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z)

    object.position = position
    object.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
    to.addChildNode(object)
}


let scene = SCNScene()
let view = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 600))

view.allowsCameraControl = true
view.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
view.scene = scene


let box = SCNBox(width: 3.0, height: 3.0, length: 3.0, chamferRadius: 0)
let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)

boxNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
scene.background.contents = UIColor.black

addShape(pos: SCNVector3Make(-1.5, 1.5, 1.5), to: boxNode)
addShape(pos: SCNVector3Make(-0.5, 1.5, 1.5), to: boxNode)
addShape(pos: SCNVector3Make(0.5, 1.5, 1.5), to: boxNode)
addShape(pos: SCNVector3Make(1.5, 1.5, 1.5), to: boxNode)

addShape(pos: SCNVector3Make(-1.5, 0.5, 1.5), to: boxNode)
addShape(pos: SCNVector3Make(-0.5, 0.5, 1.5), to: boxNode)
addShape(pos: SCNVector3Make(0.5, 0.5, 1.5), to: boxNode)
addShape(pos: SCNVector3Make(1.5, 0.5, 1.5), to: boxNode)

// and so on...

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

If i got the idea...

[image]